# Why won't my skin show up in Minecraft 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I play Minecraft 1.8, my skin won't show up. It is a 64x64 image. I have restarted my computer and logged out of my Mojang account. It loads in versions after that perfectly fine and some other people's skins won't show up for me, but some will. I have a slim skin and get the steve skin but slim for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I have a slim skin and get the steve skin but slim for some reason"?

Comment: @Banana97286 he means he gets a slim model (girl one, like how alex's arms are thinner) steve skin (just the blue shirt dude)